# Joinning different data frames with different column name

Tags: pyspark, databricks

How can I join two df that contain same names in rows with different column names. i.e:

dfSummer=

```
/ InSummer /  TripsBooked / -- /
Jon        /          3   / -- /
Tyler      /          5   / -- /
Zac        /          6   / -- /
```

dfWinter=

```
/ InWinter  / TripsBooked /  --  /
Jon         /       3  /
Tyler       /       5  /
Zac         /       6  /
```

How to represent both tables together with total trips in the year.
Thanks a lot in advance for your time

Comment: `df3 = df1.union(df2); trip_count = df3.groupby("Name", "TripsBooked").count()`, also please format your DF or read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```py
final_df = dfSummer.groupBy('InSummer').sum()\
    .join(dfWinter.groupBy('InWinter').sum(), dfSummer.InSummer == dfWinter.InWinter)
```